# Maven dependency:list shows different version than is being executed

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-dependency-plugin

Debugging my program in IntelliJ, I can see that the dependency called `registrationcore-api` is being run from the latest code in GitHub. However, running `mvn dependency:list` from my project directory shows

```
[INFO]    org.openmrs.module:registrationcore-api:jar:1.8.0:provided
```

i.e., the last release version, from last October. IntelliJ displays a warning when the debugger hits this module, saying "Source code does not match bytecode." In the editor it displays the source code for release 1.8.0.

I did recently clone `registrationcore-api` and do some work on it. But then I deleted the source code, and deleted the directories from the maven repository (`rm -r ~/.m2/repository/registrationcore*`), so that it would be downloaded on next run. Somehow, somewhere, the bytecode for the version I was working on has stuck around.

Where is it? How can I get rid of it? How is it linked in to my application, and why doesn't Maven know about it?

EDIT: I've run `mvn clean` and ensured that IntelliJ and the installed Maven are using the same repository location (`~/.m2/repository`).

Comment: Is it the same even after running `clean`?

Comment: Make sure your installed maven and maven used by IDEA are same or pointing to the same repository

Comment: @skandigraun No, that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Isuru They are both using `~/.m2/repository`, according to IntelliJ settings and the output from `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository | grep -v '\[INFO\]'`

Comment: Just a question about your `rm` above. Im pretty sure that won't delete a directory with contents. Are you sure you've deleted it from your .m2 folder?

Comment: And also, I may be a little rusty Maven, but a `provided` dependency won't get pulled down from anywhere. I'm pretty sure it means that the software project expects to find it somewhere on the filesystem already.

Comment: Whoops, I meant `rm -r`. The `provided` thing sounds like a good lead -- is that specified in the pom? How can I un-provide it?